# Insert multipe rows after specific row in Excel 2003

Tags: excel

For example, my table is like this :

```
  AAA
  bb
  cc
  AAA
  dd...
```

How can I insert 3 empty rows just below AAA row? So that, my table becomes :

```
  AAA
  first empty row
  second empty row
  third empty row
  bb
  cc
  AAA
  first empty row
  second empty row
  third empty row
  dd..
```

Comment: In VBA? Just start the macro recorder and do the steps manually. Outcome should be something like `Rows("2:4").Insert Shift:=xlDown`

Comment: What have you tried so far? And how will you determine the specific row? For instance, you could enter a criteria like "AAA" so that the rows are inserted after every cell that contains "AAA" or you could assign  your macro to a hotkey so that you can manually go to rows, then use the hotkey to insert the rows.

Answer (score 0):

If you are in Excel, right click on the row numbers on the left to show a context menu, then click on "Insert". This will add a new row.